# How to pass Value from excel to IE

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to pass value form excel sheet to IE textbox. While i run that procedure display error 438 Object doesnot support this property and method. My code is

```
Sub open()
Dim str_val1 As Object
Dim i, A As Double
marker = 0
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Dim btnGo As Object
Dim frm As Object
Dim test As Worksheet
Set test = ActiveSheet
y = 65
i = test.Cells(5, 1).Value

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))

Set objAllWindows = objShell.Windows
For Each ow In objAllWindows
  If (InStr(1, ow, "Internet Explorer", vbTextCompare)) Then
        test.Range("A" & y) = ow
        test.Range("B" & y) = ow.hwnd
        test.Range("C" & y) = ow.document.Title
        test.Range("D" & y) = ow.LocationURL
        y = y + 1


    If test.Cells(y - 1, 3).Value = "Collateral" Then
    Set IE = objShell.Windows((y - 65))
    marker = 1
    Exit For
    Else
    End If
  End If
  Next

 If marker = 0 Then
 MsgBox ("A matching webpage was NOT found")

 Else

  Set str_val1 = IE.document.getElementById("fieldName:COLLATERAL.TYPE")  <=== error
  str_val1.Value = test.Cells(i + 2, 11).Value

     End If

 End Sub
```

Thanks anyway to any help

Comment: do you confirm the id name of the element you want?  showing the html code of your page could be helpful

Comment: Yes.. Element id is fieldName:COLLATERAL.TYPE

Comment: `fieldName:COLLATERAL.TYPE` is not a usual id name.

Comment: That's from my office webpage. So i want to quick pass from my excel worksheet to the page.

Comment: no need for whole html code, just related snippet will be fine

Comment: <input class="dealbox" tabindex="0" size="4" id="fieldName:COLLATERAL.TYPE" name="fieldName:COLLATERAL.TYPE" tabname="tab1" value="" oldValue="" maxlength="3" type="text" dropdown="Y" checkFile="Y" vr="com.temenos.t24browser.validation.CheckFileValidator" autocomplete="off" onChange=" FragmentUtil.formChangeHandler(); FragmentUtil.fieldChangeHandler( event);doFieldChangeEvent(event);" onBlur="FragmentUtil.fieldChangeHandler(event);" onKeyUp="invokeHelp(event,'COLLATERAL.TYPE');" onFocus="doFieldFocusEvent(event)" ondblclick="javascript:help('COLLATERAL.TYPE')">

Answer (score 0):

Since `getelementbyid()` return error, try `getelementsbytagname()` and for-loop to find the element you want.

```vb
Dim dom_tags as object, tag as object

Set dom_tags = ie.document.getelementsbytagname("input")

for each tag in dom_tags
    msgbox tag.name
    if tag.name = "fieldName:COLLATERAL.TYPE" Then 
        set str_val1 = tag
        exit for
    end if
next tag

if str_val1 is nothing then 
    Msgbox "cannot find input tag which name is 'fieldName:COLLATERAL.TYPE'"
    ie.quit
    set ie = Nothing
else
    str_val1.Value = test.Cells(i + 2, 11).Value
end if
```

Comment: I have modified code with 

Set dom_tags = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
For Each tag In dom_tags
MsgBox tag.Name
Next 

but nothing to show up

Comment: even with

Set dom_tags = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
For Each tag In dom_tags
MsgBox ("hello")
Next